# Trying to start MySQL on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I have just installed MySQL and Im trying to start it but I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Can you copy the error message instead of posting only screenshot? Or at least cut the windows desktop part off the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the "data" directory exists, and is accessible by the user that runs mysql service